# Bot sending [object, Object] when trying to send a random embed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make it so when I say a command (ex. "!embedzay") the bot will send a random embed

I have tried pretty much all solutions from other posts I found on how to send random embeds or how to fix the [object Object] thing but they just give errors and the bot crashes[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDWSw.png).

I have managed to get sending a single embed and sending random texts to work but I can't get sending random embeds to work.

A heads up that I am very new to JavaScript so if this is a stupid question I am very sorry.
I am using JavaScript and node.js. If you need more information that what is below, please just tell me.

**here is my code for random text that works:**

```js
//rtest - random test +
    if (command === 'rtest'){
        const options = [
            "message1",
            "message2",
            "message3",
        ]

        const random = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]

        message.channel.send(`${random}`)
    }
```

**my code for embeds that works:**

```js
//embed thingy - send and embed +
    if (command === 'embedz'){
        
        message.channel.send({
            embeds: [new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle('Some title')
                .setImage('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1044759244861345862/1045783400193204335/ezgif.com-gif-maker_1.gif')],
        });
    }
```

## **...And my code for random embeds that won't work:**

**attempt one - gives [object Object] error**

```js
    if (command === 'rtest'){
        const options = [
            {embeds: new EmbedBuilder().setTitle('rtfhgfh')},
            "message2",
            "message3",
        ]

        const random = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]

        message.channel.send(`${random}`)
    }
```

**attempt two - gives cannot send empty message error**

```js
// earlier embed attempt - cannot send empty message
    if (command === 'embedzay'){
        const embed3 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('rtfhgfh')
        .setDescription('yhhfggf')

        const embed4 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('haha')
        .setDescription('bunny')

        var embedArr = [embed3, embed4];
        let randomEmbed = embedArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * embedArr.length)];
        message.channel.send(randomEmbed);
    }
```

**attempt three - back to [object Object] error**

```js
    if (command === 'embedzy'){

        const embed1 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Some title')
        .setImage('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1044759244861345862/1045783400193204335/ezgif.com-gif-maker_1.gif')

        const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Some titleuhhhhhh')
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/64l7KFc.png');

        const embeds = [embed1, embed2]

        const random = embeds[Math.floor(Math.random() * embeds.length)]

        message.channel.send(`${random}`)
    }
```

///

**attempt four - kinda works?**
Using "const myJSON = JSON.stringify();" the correct way this time
it kinda works but stuff shows up as "{"title":"Some titleuhhhhhh","image":{"url":"https://i.imgur.com/64l7KFc.png%22%7D%7D"

```js
    if (command === 'embedzye'){

        const embed1 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Some title')
        .setImage('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1044759244861345862/1045783400193204335/ezgif.com-gif-maker_1.gif')

        const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Some titleuhhhhhh')
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/64l7KFc.png');

        const embeds = [embed1, embed2]

        const random = embeds[Math.floor(Math.random() * embeds.length)]

        message.channel.send(`${JSON.stringify(random)}`)
    }
```

**attempt five - yes it works!!**

```js
    if (command === 'embedzyel'){

        const embed1 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Some title')
        .setImage('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1044759244861345862/1045783400193204335/ezgif.com-gif-maker_1.gif')

        const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Some titleuhhhhhh')
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/64l7KFc.png');

        const embeds = [embed1, embed2]

        const random = embeds[Math.floor(Math.random() * embeds.length)]


        message.channel.send({embeds: [random],});

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried JSON.stringify() ?

Comment: I just did and I got the [object][object] error again. I added the attempt to the question so you can see. Did I put it in the wrong spot?

Comment: I mean this: message.channel.send(\`${JSON.stringify(random)}\`).

Comment: Ah okay! I tried it and the stuff showed up as "{"title":"Some titleuhhhhhh","image":{"url":"https://i.imgur.com/64l7KFc.png%22%7D%7D" 
but something shows up at least! 

Krelq's answer works for me so I'm going to use that, but I really really appreciate it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        message.channel.send({
            embeds: [new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle('Some title')
                .setImage('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1044759244861345862/1045783400193204335/ezgif.com-gif-maker_1.gif')],
        });
```

This works because you send your embed packed in "embeds" object.

Edit your code and add "embeds" object.

```
const random = embeds[Math.floor(Math.random() * embeds.length)]


message.channel.send({
        embeds: [random],
});
```